# How to load land lot using arcgis api

Tags: maps, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Is there a way to load land lot view using arcgis API ? I am using this code for street view

```
var map;

      require(["esri/map", "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer", "dojo/domReady!"],
        function(Map, ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer) {

          map = new Map("map",{logo: false, 
            sliderStyle: "large"
        });

var _baseMapHost = "http://www.onemap.sg/ArcGIS/rest/services/";
var _baseMapURL = _baseMapHost + "basemap/MapServer";
var tileHost1 = "http://t1.onemap.sg/ArcGIS/rest/services/"
var tileHost2 = "http://t2.onemap.sg/ArcGIS/rest/services/"
var _baseMapURL1;
var _baseMapURL2;
 _baseMapURL = _baseMapHost + "LOT_VIEW" + "/MapServer";
 _baseMapURL1 = tileHost1 + "LOT_VIEW" + "/MapServer";
 _baseMapURL2 = tileHost2 + "LOT_VIEW" + "/MapServer";


          var tiled = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(_baseMapURL, { tileServers: [_baseMapURL1, _baseMapURL2] });
         //alert(toString(tiled)); 
          map.addLayer(tiled);
        }
      );
```

But at the place of streets , I want land lot view .

Comment: What do you mean by land lot view -- parcel boundaries? Is this data that exists in an ArcGIS basemap or data that you have and want to overlay?

Comment: it's from another server . I have done it , but it's not working in phonegap i wrote the following code

Comment: So to make sure I understand correctly, it's working in a browser now but not in phonegap?